# Invalid timestamp literal detected

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, database-migration

When trying to migrate my data from MS SQL to mySQL, essentially converting one database to another I get the following error:

```
  [WRN][copytable]: Invalid timestamp literal detected;"
```

I've attached a screenshot of what I am getting when using WorkBench.  Why would this be occuring? Size of database is 10438MB
configured at my local system with SQL SERVER 2008 R2. I had tried many 
freeware utilities for this purposes but failed to do so. Last time i 
tried using MySQL workbench to convert this database but again failed. I 
tried selection based table conversion as well as the complete database.

Comment: Seems to be a bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71350

Comment: Is there any kind of work-around that can be done?

Comment: See the comment [8 May 23:25] Jonathan Gordon on that thread (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71350).  You can run those queries in the MS-SQL database to create scripts that will make all NULL smalldatetimes into 1970-01-01.. then the second script they create will restore those back to NULL's after the migration is done.

Answer (score 1):

Quote:

> Datetime - In MYSQL datetime does not contain milliseconds. The SQL
>   Server datetime datatype contains milliseconds.  Error: “Invalid
>   timestamp literal detected” error.  Solution: Convert the datetime
>   type to a smalldatetime in SQL Server if you do not mind losing the
>   milliseconds.

[from here.](http://www.abstractnew.com/2013/04/migrating-sqlserver-to-mysql-using.html)